# Trying to understand process mitigation policies that can be set by SetProcessMitigationPolicy function

Tags: c++, security, winapi, mfc, windows-10

Sorry, if it's too broad of a question. I'm trying to see what exactly [`SetProcessMitigationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocessmitigationpolicy) function does in Windows 10, but I can't find much about it online (besides my previous forays into this subject.) I'm testing its [`PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ne-winnt-_process_mitigation_policy) options one-by-one, and I have some questions about these:

1. `ProcessSystemCallDisablePolicy` states that it "*Disables the ability to use NTUser/GDI functions at the lowest layer.*". So I'm testing it as such:

   ```
   PROCESS_MITIGATION_SYSTEM_CALL_DISABLE_POLICY pmscdp = {0};
   pmscdp.DisallowWin32kSystemCalls = 1;
   BOOL bR = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessSystemCallDisablePolicy, &pmscdp, sizeof(pmscdp));
   int err = ::GetLastError();

   ::GdiFlush();   //Try to trip it here
   ```

   But it always fails with error code 19, or `ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT`.

   So what exactly is it supposed to do and how do I set it?
2. `ProcessExtensionPointDisablePolicy` states that it "*... prevents legacy extension point DLLs from being loaded into the process.*"

   ```
   PROCESS_MITIGATION_EXTENSION_POINT_DISABLE_POLICY pmepdp = {0};
   pmepdp.DisableExtensionPoints = 1;
   BOOL bR = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessExtensionPointDisablePolicy, &pmepdp, sizeof(pmepdp));
   int err = ::GetLastError();
   ```

   Sorry for my naivete, but what is the `extension point DLL`? And how can I test one?
3. `ProcessSignaturePolicy` states that it can "*restrict image loading to those images that are either signed by Microsoft, by the Windows Store, or by Microsoft, the Windows Store and the Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL)*".

   First off, it seems to have no effect on `CreateProcess` and only works with `LoadLibrary`-type functions. So if I do this:

   ```
   PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY pmbsp = {0};
   pmbsp.MicrosoftSignedOnly = 1;
   //pmbsp.StoreSignedOnly = 1;   //always seems to fail with this flag
   //pmbsp.MitigationOptIn = 1;   //Doesn't seem to have any effect
   BOOL bR = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessSignaturePolicy, &pmbsp, sizeof(pmbsp));
   BOOL err = ::GetLastError();
   ```

   And then try to load some of my test DLLs:

   ```
   HMODULE hModDll = ::LoadLibrary(L".\\Dll1.dll");
   ```

   The `LoadLibrary` function fails with the `MessageBox` that reads:

   > Bad Image
   >
   > Dll-Name is either not designed to run on Windows or it
   >   contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original
   >   installation media or contact your system administrator or the
   >   software vendor for support. Error status 0xc0000428.

   Interestingly, if I call it on some `System32` DLL that is not signed:

   ```
   HMODULE hModDll = ::LoadLibrary(L"iologmsg.dll");
   ```

   it seems to work fine. But if I place a copy of my test `Dll1.dll` into `System32` folder and load it this way:

   ```
   HMODULE hModDll = ::LoadLibrary(L"Dll1_.dll");
   ```

   it still fails with the same message box:

   [image]

   This is interesting. How can it tell the difference between `iologmsg.dll` and `Dll1_.dll`? Both files aren't signed.

   PS. And that modal message box can throw in a really nasty wrench into the mix if the app (or the service) does not expect any UI to be shown there.
4. `ProcessFontDisablePolicy` lastly, I'm totally lost about this one. It states that it "*turns off the ability of the process to load non-system fonts.*"

   So after I enable it in my MFC GUI app:

   ```
   PROCESS_MITIGATION_FONT_DISABLE_POLICY  pmfdp = {0};
   pmfdp.DisableNonSystemFonts = 1;
   BOOL bR = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessFontDisablePolicy, &pmfdp, sizeof(pmfdp));
   int err = ::GetLastError();
   ```

   the app has a [Richedit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?view=vs-2017) that I can load a custom font in. So I went online and downloaded a [totally random font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Action-Man). Then installed it in Windows Explorer and tried to use it from the app after that policy has been enabled:

   ```
   //Set format for the text window
   CHARFORMAT cf = { 0 };
   cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
   cf.dwMask = CFM_FACE | CFM_SIZE;
   cf.yHeight = 18 * 20;
   VERIFY(SUCCEEDED(::StringCchCopy(cf.szFaceName, _countof(cf.szFaceName), L"Action Man")));
   VERIFY(SetDefaultCharFormat(cf));
   ```

   The app was able to display and use that (clearly non-system) font without any issues:

   [image]

   So what am I missing here in that policy?

Comment: really almost all windows binary signed. some direct, some have external signature in *cat* files - need hash file and search hash in cat (https://pastebin.com/eVzGZ7ih)

Comment: Question is too broad, these should be 4 individual questions.

Comment: @RbMm: Hah, I didn't know that you can sign a dll thru a .cab file. I learned something today. Thanks! Is that .cab file just a container for signatures? It seems like all those .cab files have more than one signature in them. Also what's the purpose of doing it instead of just signing the dll itself? I also tried to follow your code example -- can you add some comments to explain what you're doing there. It seems like the `WinVerifyTrust` function can be called outside the `while` loop without affecting anything.

Comment: yes, *cat* file is container for signatures. in my concrete code `WinVerifyTrust` use pointer `&wtd`, which use `&wci`, but `wci` use `ci.wszCatalogFile` which updated by call `CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext` inside loop

Comment: [*Catalog Files and Digital Signatures*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/catalog-files)

Comment: As for 1) you can't do it if any DLL that will do a syscall on win32k.sys (the windowing subsystem) is **already** loaded. So basically, try to do it in a console program **without** having `user32.dll` or `gdi32.dll` linked to your program: load one of these DLL dynamically (`LoadLibrary`) and try to do a call through a pointer obtained with `GetProcAddress`: it should not work.

Comment: @Neitsa: Oh dude, appreciate it! I didn't think about it. I was testing it in a console app already, but when I added my `GdiFlush()` call it automatically statically linked the executable to `gdi32.dll`. Now when I removed it and the only dependency is `kernel32.dll` I'm able to set the `ProcessSystemCallDisablePolicy` mitigation and `LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll")` returns error code `ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED`. I would've never thought of it myself! Love moments like that! One follow-up I have for you is which DLLs are affected by that policy, is it just `user32.dll` and `gdi32.dll` only?

Comment: @c00000fd : the check is done in kernel-land, in the system service call dispatcher (the check is done on the `EPROCESS` structure - basically describes a process from a kernel point of view -  where there's a field called `MitigationFlagsValues` which is a structure with a field called `DisallowWin32kSystemCalls`). Put simply any call to the windowing subsystem will fail, whatever the DLL is. It can't be bypassed from user-land as the check is done in kernel, so even a ASM stub with a SYSCALL instruction will fail.

Comment: @Neitsa: Well, `ntdll.dll` also makes `syscall`s but it's not being blocked.

Comment: @c00000fd: for `DisallowWin32kSystemCalls` the filtering occurs **only** for syscalls that are directed towards win32k.sys. There are two types of syscalls in windows: the ones that are made to the kernel, or the ones that are directed to the windowing subsystem (in this case the 12th bit of the syscall number is set to 1).

Comment: @Neitsa: Hmm. I see. So what you're saying is that in the user-land there can be pretty much any dll besides `user32.dll` and `gdi32.dll` that can make those syscalls to `win32k.sys`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186047/discussion-between-neitsa-and-c00000fd).

Comment: Well by using the underlying mechanism any code (not just DLLs) can make calls that will end up in a SSDT. Since MS rearranged them, you can find most of those relevant to you in win32u.dll now (user mode counterpart to win32k.sys). These days gdi32.dll and user32.dll use those functions from win32u.dll instead of _making_ the system calls (to win32k.sys) themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is guessing, but since many links in the function's documentation are 404s, I believe that the following would be valid:

1.Probably not implemented, yet.

2.Only a guess (since the link is also 404), but it might refer to DLLs used in obsolete situtations (like the XP and below login DLL, replaced in Vista with [Credential Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/credentialprovider/)).

3.Windows DLLs are treated as signed (without actually having a digital signature attached), not only because they reside in System32, but because Windows keeps internally a map for them. For your DLLs, it won't work. Also, this has no point in CreateProcess() because the new process cannot interact with yours (without your knowledge) and, therefore, cannot hijack it, where a DLL loaded with LoadLibrary can do anything to ruin your process.

4.It probably refers to fonts not installed by Explorer, but fonts added with [AddFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea).

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I can definitely attest to point 4. Just tried it and it blocks `AddFontResource`. Why are they so concerned about loading fonts though? Also on point 2, I found [this little tidbit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute) -- search for `Extension Point Disable policy`. I tried to see if it blocks `AppInit DLLs`. Well, those seem to be blocked by default on Win10. So I couldn't confirm. Then tried `SetWindowsHookEx` with global hook but that was able to set w/o any problems. So I'm still lost.

Comment: @c00000fd TrueType fonts can include [hinting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#Hinting_language) code that has to be run in a VM and can be subject to exploits.

Comment: Thanks for this docs link @c00000fd, Microsoft docs on these mitigations are messy and in all places. Turns out this mitigation also disables "legacy" IME (I assume imm32 rather than TSF COM API?). Anyways turning it on prevented IME input... Just putting it out there in case anyone runs into the same issue and ends up here.